# Dropbear only starts after update-initramfs

Tags: debian, dropbear

I've installed dropbear to be able to remotely decrypt my LUKS partition.
It worked flawlessly after executing `update-initramfs -u`, however one restart later the dropbear daemon didn't seem to start as the SSH connection times out.
After decrypting (non-remotely), executing `update-initramfs` -u and rebooting again it works flawlessly. My server runs Debian 11 and Dropbear v2020.81

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the right port when you try to login the next time? the standard howto runs the initramfs dropbear on 2222

Comment: Yes. I am connecting to port 2222, which works directly after updating the initramfs and restarting. One restart after that and there doesn’t seem to be a listener behind port 2222.